Await TeamsInfo.getMember leads to RestError / ServiceError
We have successfully implemented a Bot within the Bot Framework from Microsoft. It works fine for most users, but for some users we receive a RestError when trying to get the TeamsInfo:
TeamsInfo response:
{
    "error": {
        "name": "RestError",
        "code": "ServiceError",
        "statusCode": 400,
        "request": {
            "streamResponseStatusCodes": {},
            "url": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/..."
        }
    }
}

Our code:
await TeamsInfo.getMember(context, context.activity.from.id)

It happens quite often a day. After a few minutes, it disappears for the same user. We do understand that there is nothing like a 100% SLA, but this appears quite regularly.
Our bot has implemented justInTimeInstallation (thanks to StackOverflow):
https://github.com/SubbaReddi/89.teams-just-in-time-installation
We can see from the log that JIT is triggered. However, the error persists and then suddenly disappears.
Does anyone have any idea what this error means and how to prevent it?
Thank you very much!

Ok, we have found the solution ourselves. For everyone:
When you have a bot in Microsoft Teams and you receive a RestError, this usually means that the conversation has not started. Just inform the user to start the conversation and everything is fine.
